# Creacion de nuevo arreglo con subdocumentos

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
let array = [
    {"hora":"19:30"},
    {"hora":"20:00"},
    ]
```

Y luego tengo estos datos:

```
let turnos = [
{"hora_turno": "19:30", "nombre":"pedro"},
{"hora_turno": "20:00", "nombre":"juan"},
]
```

Y quiero crear un array que resulte así:

```
let diaTurno = [
{
"hora":"19:30",
"turnos":[
 {"hora_turno": "19:30", "nombre":"pedro"},
]
},
{
"hora":"20:00",
"turnos":[
 {"hora_turno": "20:00", "nombre":"juan"},
]
}
]
```

Es decir, realizar un arreglo y que el primer parametro sea la hora del turno y luego un parametro turno el cual contenga los turnos que coincidan con la hora
Ej: En el objeto del turno de las 19:30, quiero agregarle un subarreglo llamado turnos que contengan todos los turnos que coincidan con la hora del turno (19:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O yo entendí mal, o lo que tu pides no tiene mucho sentido. Porque no se necesita el primer array

Puedes ocupar la función [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para convertir

```js
let turnos = [
{"hora_turno": "19:30", "nombre":"pedro"},
{"hora_turno": "20:00", "nombre":"juan"},
];

let NewTurnos = turnos.map(function (e) {
    return {
        hora: e.hora_turno,
        turnos: [e]
    }
});

console.log(NewTurnos);
```